# Sound pressure level meter for ultrasounds

Tags: high-frequency, spl

I've been reading some datasheets about sound pressure level meters and most of them seem to measure sound in the frequency range 0-8.5 kHz.

Is it just that this is where their greatest sensibility is or don't they measure anyting outside this band?

What is the difference between this devices and the ones that measure up to 90 kHz. Why are the last ones so expensive?

Comment: Yes these devices exist. Googling using your title finds a wide range from various manufacturers. You can find out how much they will cost to ship to wherever you are, or whether you have a local stockist. Hardware recommendations are not going to be on topic here.

Comment: The only one I could find that works in this frequency range was the Svantek SVAN912AE and it is over 1000 dollars, I couldn't find a wide range from various manufacturers with these especifications. Where should I post this question to receive hardware recomendation?

Comment: I don't know which sites are for hardware recommendations. And if the price of these devices is in the £1000 range then that's what you'll need to budget for :-)

Comment: Already edited the question